# TDengine - invalid operation

Tags: tdengine

I was trying to execute sql:

```
select last(*) from mytable where index=index-1
```

Describe mytable:

```
             Field              |         Type         |   Length    |   Note   |
=================================================================================
 ts                             | TIMESTAMP            |           8 |          |
 gauge                          | DOUBLE               |           8 |          |
 index                          | NCHAR                |          11 | TAG      |
```

The result occur error:

```
Invalid operation
```

Answer (score 0):

index is nchar type so you should change the SQL to

```
select last(*) from mytable where index='some_value';
```